# SQL query involving 2 tables

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables like this:

```
Table_1          Table_2
---------------  -------------------
id  bk_title     bk_no  bk_isbn
---------------  ---------------------
1   A_Book       1      ISBN0001
2   B_Book       1      ISBN0002
                 2      ISBN0003
```

I want to fetch records as:

```
BK_Title    Num_Copies
----------------------------
A_Book      2
B_Book      1
```

Any SQL example would be of great help for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple `INNER JOIN` and `GROUP BY` with a `COUNT`:

```
Select  T1.bk_title, Count(*) As Num_Copies
From    Table_1 T1
Join    Table_2 T2  On  T1.id = T2.bk_no
Group by T1.bk_title
```